# Censoring data for survival analysis

Tags: r

I have a dataset with clients that might or might not have experienced the event before the end.

All of them start at their time 0. However, some clients have data for 2 years and others for only one month. I want to know if that person with only one month is being counted as death afterwards (censored but death) or if it is being treated differently.

This is my code:

```
km_fit <- survfit(Surv(mes,estado) ~ 1,data = survival_clientes)
surv_summary(km_fit)
```

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Can you post an example of data you have, or create a reproducible example, and explain exactly what you want to know in terms of the data (not jargon)?

Comment: The `estado` variable column will determine whether the `survfit` function will consider the time measure in `mes` as representing event or censoring. The `1` in the formula has nothing to do with that difference. It is telling the `survfit` function that there is only a single stratum.